# Implementing Add trait for an enum without moving data

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a recursive enum for something like a parse tree. Currently my starting point looks like this:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Value<T: Add + Copy> {
    Sum(Rc<Value<T>>, Rc<Value<T>>),
    Scalar(T)
}
```

Obviously I only care about addition for now and will add other operations later. I want to implement the `Add` trait to enable the following:

```
let x = Value<f32>::Scalar(0.3);
let y = Value<f32>::Scalar(0.3);
let z = x + y;
```

`z` should now be a `Value<f32>::Sum` and `x` and `y` should not be moved. My question is how to implement the `Add` trait. Or rather for which types. My first approach looked like this:

```
impl<T: Add + Copy> Add for crate::Value<T> {
    type Output = Self;

    fn add(self, other: Value<T>) -> Self {
        ...
    }
}
```

This solution compiles, but the data is moved. If I try to change the parameters of the `add` method to references, it fails because the signature does not match the expected one. Makes sense, so I tried to implement the trait for `&Value<T>`. That seems to work, but I cannot write `x + y` anymore, because they are not references. I also struggled with the return type, because it cannot be `&Value<T>` but must be `Value<T>`.

I took another approach to completely work with `Rc<Value<T>>` but I'm not allowed to implement `Add` for `Rc<...>`. I'm aware that there is a `AsRef` trait, but I'm quite new to Rust and have now idea how it would fit into my use case.

Any hint how to put those pieces together and get them working would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, you could keep your approach with `Rc` but wrap it in your own type:

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::ops::Add;

#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
struct WrapperValue<T: Add + Copy>(Rc<Value<T>>);

#[derive(Debug)]
enum Value<T: Add + Copy> {
    Sum(WrapperValue<T>, WrapperValue<T>),
    Scalar(T)
}

impl<T: Add + Copy> Add for WrapperValue<T> {
    type Output = WrapperValue<T>;

    fn add(self, other: WrapperValue<T>) -> Self {
        WrapperValue(Rc::new(Value::Sum(self.clone(), other.clone())))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ef15c174a14cffd2df06eeddfa4f743f)

As you mentioned you dont want to move the value, you can also implement it for `&`:

```rust
impl<T: Add + Copy> Add for &WrapperValue<T> {
    type Output = WrapperValue<T>;

    fn add(self, other: &WrapperValue<T>) -> Self::Output {
        WrapperValue(Rc::new(Value::Sum(self.clone(), other.clone())))
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=93f2243a39cf1f527aaa4abaf1dd206e)

Comment: This compiles, but if I create two instances of WrapperValue and add them via "+" the data is still moved.

Comment: But now you have to write `&x + &y`. I wanted to write `x + y` and not move the data. I start to doubt that it's possible. Might work with types that implement `Copy` but that's not possible for `Rc`.

Comment: @Achim afaik you can not, it is because of the bounds of the trait itself. you would have to chose i think :(